# where does sprintf store the file

Tags: c++

I was debugging a code which has the following line:

```
    char file_name[128];
      sprintf(file_name, "layer-%03d-%02d-out.csv", c, i);
       CSV::SaveVector(file_name, current_vector);

int SaveVector(const std::string &filename, const Perceptron::EigenVector &v) {
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename.c_str(), "w");
  if (!fp) {
    MinLog("Failed to open file %s\n", filename.c_str());
    return FILE_ERROR;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
    fprintf(fp, "%s%.16lf", (i>0 ? " ," : ""),  static_cast<double>(v[i]));
  }

  fclose(fp);

  return NO_ERRORS;
}
```

The statement does not give any error, but I don't find the file_name in any location in my current folder. Where will this file be saved?

Comment: What file are you talking about? This is just a formatted print statement that doesn't have anything to do with files.

Comment: .csv string that needs to be put in file_name above

Comment: That's not a file. That's just a text string.

Comment: Yes the file_name itself I cannot find either. Where is the the file that contains the text string? I cannot find it

Comment: There is no file involved here. The "file_name" is just an arbitrary name that doesn't have any effect on the function of the code. This code has nothing to do with files at all, except that it involves a variable called "file_name". -- By the way, you asked the wrong question. The right question is either "What does this line of code do?" or "Where does (some other piece of code that stores files) store the file?"

Comment: Are you running from within an IDE or from the command line? If from an IDE look in the project directory.

Comment: I tried doing both. I  also ran from the command line C:\GITOCRrepository\ocr\bin.x86-windows.debug\test_code.ext arg1 arg2. I don;t find the file in Project directory either.

Comment: Add the following just before you open the file: `std::cerr << get_current_dir_name() << "\n";` On windows: `char buffer[5000];std::cerr << _getcwd(buffer, 5000) << "\n";`

Answer (score 5):

sprintf writes to a string. It has nothing to do with writing to files. Which means `file_name` is a string. You'll have to look at what is done with that afterwards.

Comment: I put the one code one line before I had. I don't know where file_name file is located.

Comment: There is no "file_name file". This code has nothing to do with files. It just fills in a variable called "file_name" with a string. Please read the documentation for [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: I posted the entire code now David and the SaveVector function does the work

Comment: Still I cannot find the file where it is located.

Comment: Print the full path of the file `fp`. If it saved the file, that's where it will be.

Answer (score 3):

`sprintf` does not create a file.  It just allows you to 'print' a formatted string into a buffer of your choosing.  In your case, it looks like that was done to create a filename.  You need to add another line like:

```
FILE *f = fopen(file_name, "w");
```

To create and open that file for writing, if that's your goal.

Comment: @Loki, I'm sorry, why?  There's no indication OP wants to use `sprintf` to print *into* the file, is there?

Comment: Carl sorry I did not post the entire code. Please see the SaveVector function that does write to a file.

Comment: Still I cannot find the location of the file.

Comment: What's the working directory of the program?

Comment: You mean where the Visual Studio project is. I checked there but could not find it.

Comment: I found the problem Windows was keeping this file hidden and then it was not visible to me unfortunately. I found it eventually in the hidden file. Sorry guys for my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

`sprintf` doesn't write data to files. It writes data to strings. After that call, file_name will contain something like `layer-123-234-out.csv`.

You'll want to look for a call like `fopen` or `fwrite`, which is where the actual writing will happen.

Comment: Bill sorry I did not post the entire code. Please see the SaveVector function that does write to a file. Still I cannot find the file.

Answer (score 2):

`int sprintf ( char * str, const char * format, ... );`

Write formatted data to string
Composes a string with the same text that would be printed if format was used on printf, but instead of being printed, the content is stored as a C string in the buffer pointed by str.

Where did you get that it writes to a file? I think you don't understand the usage for this. :)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/